# Phoenix listing; how to show foreign key name instead of foreign key id

Tags: elixir

```
Template code includes:
  <%= for shift <- @shifts do %>
<tr>
  <td><%= shift.user_id %></td>
  <td><%= shift.start_time %></td>
  <td><%= shift.end_time %></td>
  <td><%= shift.roster_id %></td>
```

How can I show the username and rostername from their respective schemas?
I can pass @users and @rosters to the template but do not know how to use with above 'for' loop.

Comment: Have you preloaded the association? If yes then something like `<%= shift.user.name %>`?

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about preloading. Now working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the contrary to other data access libraries, Ecto is very explicit. It will not fetch you any associations for your results in query unless you request them directly.

To request them you have two options: build your own query or simply use `preload`.

Preload is also available in two flavors - one is to append this command in the existing query:

```
from u in User, where: u.id == ^user_id, preload: [:profile]
```

or to use it as a Repo's function:

```
User
|> Repo.get(user_id)
|> Repo.preload([:profile])
```

The outcome is the same.